# NUnit Setup seems to not call WebDriver after first test completes

Tags: selenium, nunit

I'm running into an issue that seems to be related to `webdriver/nunit`.

On the initial running my first test `[Setup]` and `[Teardown]` work.  When the system tries to run my next test, which requires a `[Setup]` it doesn't seem as though the `WebDriver` is called.

```
[SetUp]
//This has to be done for all tests.  It is the setup I say!
public void Setup()
{
    LaunchBrowser();
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45));
}

[TearDown]
//This has to be done for all tests.  It is the teardown I say!
public void TearItDown()
{
      driver.Dispose();
}
```

If I comment out the `[Teardown]`, all my tests run no problem.

```
LaunchBrowser()

public static IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

public string landingPage = "http://www.smartdrive.net";

public void LaunchBrowser() 
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(landingPage);
}
```

I have tried on the last test to add a `driver.Dispose();` figuring I could just close the session once all tests run, but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

error I receive with `[Teardown]` in place

```
Result Message: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:51089
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
at UnitTestProject1.Browser_Landing.getLandingPlacement() in c:\Users\erikag\Desktop\AutomationTests\VS_NetSeleniumTest\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1\Browser_Landing.cs:line 30
            at UnitTestProject1.ServiceConsoleTest.PlacementChk() in c:\Users\erikag\Desktop\AutomationTests\VS_NetSeleniumTest\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1\TestSuite_LandLog.cs:line 46
```

I did read somewhere that the issue was correlated to the `webdriver` having issues relaunching after the the `[Teardown]`, but I can't seem to figure out how to work around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are disposing the driver after every run but not instantiating before each run. So driver won't work as expected. Instantiate the driver inside `LaunchBrowser()` method and re-run the tests

Just more info `Dispose()` resets the diver and, thus the instance is not valid anymore with the code block you posted. See [this](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html)

And, best practice is probably using `Quit` instead of `Dispose` because `Quit()` calls `Dispose` and does some more clean up so you don't have to use `Dispose` separately.

And, with the change the `LaunchBrowser()` method should look like the following:

```
public IWebDriver Driver;

public string landingPage = "http://www.smartdrive.net";

public void LaunchBrowser() 
{
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(landingPage);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Saifur for your response.  I changed to driver.Quit(); and got the same error:

[TearDown]
        //This has to be done for all tests.  It is the teardown I say!
        public void TearItDown()
        {
                    driver.Quit();
        }
      
Any other ideas?

Comment: You need to instantiate the driver inside `LaunchBrowser()`   `public void LaunchBrowser() 
{
 driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(landingPage);
}`

Comment: isn't your edit already what i have as my launchbrowser? and if that were the issue wouldn't it have failed for my first test? The first test works no problem and with teardown commented out all of my tests pass.  So would it be correlated to the instaintiation of the WebDriver?  If that were the problem area, wouldn't all of the tests fail on setup?   Sorry, I'm going to test with the firefox driver and see if I have any different behavior, i tend to find a lot has to do with the IE drivers, but if that's the case i have to make this work with IE.  Thanks for your help investigating!

Comment: @RenMG NO It's not. I am instantiating the `driver` inside `LaunchBrowser() ` with `driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();` and you are doing it once outside. The reason it works first time because the class where the `LaunchBrowser() ` method reside instantiate first time. After that you are Disposing the driver, and calling the `LaunchBrowser() ` method which does not have  `driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();` line and thus does not instantiate the driver. Hope that make sense

Comment: that makes sense now, thanks! I'm doing it now and it totally worked!  I really appreciate you re-explaining it.  It's these little placement details that i'm still learning to not take for granted.  I really appreciate your time!! HIGH FIVE!

Comment: Glad it helped you. Don't forget to upvote as well :)